# Syncronize file with table

Tags: database, optimization, integration, batch-processing

We are receiving from partner the excell file with list of products. We need to update table that contains these products with data from file. For example some product information was updated, some new products were added , or some removed.

We currently selecting all products for partner in memory, making a diff with products received from from file. The diff will contain list of new products, products to delete, products to update. Than we are applying updates, inserts and deletes.

The approach works, especially if there are not a lot of products, but when there are a lot, memory became an issue. Does anyone had similar tasks, what are the approaches you used? Or any useful advises?

Also we are using a lot of 'home made' libs for this, I am  just wondering, if there are already some libs for this already available( googling didn't helped me a lot)?

Thanks a lot for advises!
Best regards, Alex

Comment: What database are you using: SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle ?

Comment: we are using Oracle and H2 for tests

Comment: Sorry, I'm only familiar with SQL Server... For Oracle, there're equivalent [data integration technology](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/doc.1111/e14860/golden_gate.htm#FMWLC406) which should be suitable for complex ETL approach. As for the memory issue, what about using procedure and cursor ? Lookup excel files' data per row in your database, then update / insert according to the situation (MERGE in Oracle and UPSERT in Postgresql). It takes longer to execute, but no memory problem any more.

Comment: we have some home made solutions that uses cursors to optimize memory usage. Just was searching for something not home made :)